# Android API 19 vs 20

Tags: android, eclipse, api

I am using eclipse and I cannot drag a text field number into the graphical interface. I figured out that the problem is that I am using API 20 : Android 4.4.w and that causes issues. I need API 19 but i cannot seem to find/download it anywhere. Can someone please direct me with some help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the API 19 SDK Platform via your SDK Manager:

[image: SDK Manager, showing API Level 19 items]

Comment: Great! I typically use jgrasp so I was not sure how to do it. I really appreciate it! Thank you.